# Jquery Grid Alternative row color and Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on Jquery Grid. I need some help in the following scenario:

1) I need to set the alternating row color of the JQuery Grid Rows.

2) I need to remove extra space when there is no scroll bar i.e. Jquery Grid preserves extra space for scroll bar and if the records are very few it hides the scroll bar but that extra space still there. In this condition i want to remove that extra space.

Please give me some suggestion to complete my task.

Comment: can you provide us with some code or jsfiddle?